# Is there a way to put buttons inside a SwiftUI cell view?

Tags: swiftui

I have a SwiftUI List showing some cells. I want to put 3 buttons inside each cell. I want the user to able to tap each without selecting the cell or triggering the other buttons.
The code I have now triggers all 3 buttons when the user taps the cell.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var names = ["Mohamed", "Ahmed", "Ali"]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(names, id: \.self) { name in
                    NameCell(name: name)
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Names")
        }
    }
}

struct NameCell: View {
    let name: String

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
            Text(name)
                .font(.headline)
            HStack {
                Button("Action1") { print("action 1 tapped") }
                Button("Action2") { print("action 2 tapped") }
                Button("Action3") { print("action 3 tapped") }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The solution in [this topic can be helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61188131/swiftui-mvvm-coordinator-router-navigationlink)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks a bug in `SwiftUI`, while using button inside cell whole area is tappable. to solve this you can replace `Button` with  `Text` and for action add `TapGesture` to `Text`.

Please try below code.

```
struct NameCell: View {

 ....            
      HStack(spacing: 10) {

          Text("Action1").onTapGesture {
                  print("action 1 tapped")
          }
          Text("Action2").onTapGesture {
                  print("action 2 tapped")
          }
          Text("Action3").onTapGesture {
                  print("action 3 tapped")
          }
    }
  ....
}
```