# View With Multiple Buttons To Go Respective Forwarding Views

Tags: ios, button, swiftui

I have several vertically-stacked two pairs of rectangles (`Rectangle()`), each of which has a `Button`.  When the user taps a button, the user needs to be forwarded to a specific `View`.  For instance, if they tap Alice, the user needs to be forwarded to AliceView.

[image]

If it's just the matter of one button, forwarding the user from the current `View` to another isn't a problem.  Anyway, the following is what I have.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var canAlice: Bool = false
    @State var canKim: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                HStack(spacing: 0) {
                    // ZStack: A view that overlays its children, aligning them in both axes.
                    ZStack {
                        Rectangle().frame(width: UIScreen.screenWidth / 2.0, height: UIScreen.screenWidth / 2.0, alignment: .topLeading)
                            .foregroundColor(.orange)
                            .border(Color.yellow, width: 2)
                        Button(action: {
                            self.canAlice = true
                        }, label: {
                            Text("Alice")
                            .font(.largeTitle)
                            .background(Color.black)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                        })
                        NavigationLink(destination: AliceView(), isActive: $canAlice) { EmptyView() }
                    }
                    ZStack {
                        Rectangle().frame(width: UIScreen.screenWidth / 2.0, height: UIScreen.screenWidth / 2.0, alignment: .topLeading)
                            .foregroundColor(.orange)
                            .border(Color.yellow, width: 2)
                        Button(action: {
                            self.canKim = true
                        }, label: {
                            Text("Kim")
                                .font(.largeTitle)
                                .background(Color.black)
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                        })
                        NavigationLink(destination: KimView(), isActive: $canKim) { EmptyView() }
                    }
                }.listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())

                HStack(spacing: 0) {
                    ...
                    ...
                    ...
                }.listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())

                HStack(spacing: 0) {
                    ...
                    ...
                    ...
                }.listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())

                HStack(spacing: 0) {
                    ...
                    ...
                    ...
                }.listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
            }
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            .statusBar(hidden: true)
        }
    }
}
```

Now, if I tap the Alice button, the current `View` transitions to AliceView, comes back to the current `View` and then transitions to KimView.  How can I have multiple buttons within a single `View` and forward the user to respective `View`s?  I'm new to SwiftUI.  Thanks.

**UPDATE**

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selection: Int? = 0

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                HStack(spacing: 0) {
                    // ZStack: A view that overlays its children, aligning them in both axes.
                    ZStack {
                        Rectangle().frame(width: UIScreen.screenWidth / 2.0, height: UIScreen.screenWidth / 2.0, alignment: .topLeading)
                            .foregroundColor(.orange)
                            .border(Color.yellow, width: 2)
                        Button(action: {
                            self.selection = 1
                        }, label: {
                            Text("Alice")
                                .font(.largeTitle)
                                .background(Color.black)
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                        })
                        NavigationLink(destination: AliceView(), tag: 1, selection: self.$selection) { EmptyView() }
                    }
                    ZStack {
                        Rectangle().frame(width: UIScreen.screenWidth / 2.0, height: UIScreen.screenWidth / 2.0, alignment: .topLeading)
                            .foregroundColor(.orange)
                            .border(Color.yellow, width: 2)
                        Button(action: {
                            self.selection = 2
                        }, label: {
                            Text("Kim")
                                .font(.largeTitle)
                                .background(Color.black)
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                        })
                        NavigationLink(destination: KimView(), tag: 2, selection: self.$selection) { EmptyView() }
                    }
                }.listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())

                HStack(spacing: 0) {
                    ...
                    ...
                    ...
                }.listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())

                HStack(spacing: 0) {
                    ...
                    ...
                    ...
                }.listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())

                HStack(spacing: 0) {
                    ...
                    ...
                    ...
                }.listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
            }
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            .statusBar(hidden: true)
        }
    }
}
```

Now, when I tap Alice or Kim, I won't transition to another view and then bounce back to the initial view.  Whether I tap Alice or Kim, I transition to AliceView.

Comment: The solution for similar scenario was provided in [SwiftUI MVVM Coordinator/Router/NavigationLink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61188788/12299030)

Comment: @Asperi I've made some changes according to your answer.  Now, whether I tap Alice or Kim, I end up transitioning to KimView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution (by approach referenced in comment). Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4

[image]

Button style to hide a link:

```
struct LinkButtonStyle<D: View>: ButtonStyle {
    let destination: D
    @Binding var isActive: Bool

    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .background(NavigationLink(destination: self.destination, isActive: $isActive) { EmptyView() })
    }
}
```

and an example of modified cell

```
ZStack {
    Rectangle().frame(width: UIScreen.screenWidth / 2.0, height: UIScreen.screenWidth / 2.0, alignment: .topLeading)
        .foregroundColor(.orange)
        .border(Color.yellow, width: 2)
    Button(action: {
        self.canAlice = true
    }, label: {
        Text("Alice")
        .font(.largeTitle)
        .background(Color.black)
        .foregroundColor(.white)
    }).buttonStyle(LinkButtonStyle(destination: AliceView(), isActive: $canAlice))
}
```

Comment: Yes.  It works.  Thanks a lot.  Just one question...  What if I don't want to hide the link?

Comment: You saved a fortune for me! Thanks a lot for the brilliant solution!

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this using a single `Bool` for `isActice` parameter and a single `NavigationLink`. Also need to add a destination parameter outside the `body`. And set the destination in the button action. Here's an example:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var showNextView = false
    var destination = GeorgeView()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                HStack(spacing: 0) {
                    NavigationLink(destination: destination, isActive: $showNextView) { EmptyView() }
                    // Rest of your implementation...
                        Button(action: {
                            self.destination = KimView()
                            self.showNextView = true
                        }, label: {
                            Text("Kim")
                            .font(.largeTitle)
                            .background(Color.black)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                        })
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I get multiple errors at the line of self.destination = KimView().  1. Cannot assign to property: 'self' is immutable  2. Cannot assign value of type 'KimView' to type 'GeorgeView'